# How do I use Scala code in JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, scala, interface

#### I am trying to access a Scala API from a native JavaScript application.

I have tried using the `npm java` package to get it to run since Scala is compiled to Java bytecode, but trying to access classes only result in type errors such as this one.

```
/home/path/to/my/project/bin/Solver.js:62
    var glue = this.java.newInstanceSync("Tape.typeWrapper");
                         ^

Error: Error creating class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void scala.App.$init$(scala.App)'
    at Tape.typeWrapper.<init>(Tape.scala:6)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)

    at new Solver (/home/path/to/my/project/bin/Solver.js:62:26)
```

#### I need help with finding a Scala/JavaScript interface which allows me to store Scala objects and call methods from the Scala code.

Comment: The scala library and possibly other dependencies have to be on the classpath.

Comment: It may help if you explain why do you need to call **Scala** code from **JS**, also the environment in which you are running. Finally, you may want to give it a try to **ScalaJS** which compiles Scala code to JS, or **GraalVM** which let's you write polyglot applications.